# How to use ICU C++ API on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, icu

I would like to use [ICU's](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/index.html) C++ API, specifically the `UnicodeString` class, in a macOS app. I see that I can include headers for the C API from Xcode, but I don't see headers for the C++ API.

```
% PLAT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform
% ls $PLAT/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unicode
localpointer.h      ptypes.h        ...     ustring.h        
... other C API headers ...
```

But [`unistr.h`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/unistr_8h.html) and other C++ headers are not there. The `unistr.h` file declares the `UnicodeString` class.

However, if I look at this library file, it seems the library does contain the class.

```
% c++filt < $PLAT/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libicucore.A.tbd | grep icu::UnicodeString
...
icu::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(char16_t const*),  
icu::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(char16_t const*, int), 
icu::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(char const*),  
...
```

Anyone using C++ ICU for a macOS app? How do you do it?

Comment: I've not used ICU that way.  I did the `brew install icu4c` and followed the https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu/howtouseicu.html documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand homebrew security, so I worry about downloading malware. But `brew` is everywhere so I guess I need to learn to use it.